# difference between 'util.promisify(setTimeout)' and 'ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Environment: node 8.11.x
I want use async/await for sleep a while.

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
await sleep(5000)
```

This works.

```
const sleep = util.promisify(setTimeout)
await sleep(5000)
```

It cause a exception: TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function.
[setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) The document note: This method has a custom variant for promises that is available using util.promisify()

So what's the difference?

Comment: that's very interesting about the custom variant - you know what's interesting about it? the code you says "cause an exception" ... **doesn't** - it works - in node 10.8.0 - so perhaps there's a bug in 8.11.x (whatever that is)

Answer (score 12):

`promisify` is expects a function that has final argument that is the callback.

In other a words it wants a function that looks like:

```
function takesACallback(str, Fn) {
    Fn(null, "got: ", str)
    // or with an error:
    // Fn(error)
}
```

Of course `setTimout` is the opposite. The argument you want to pass in is the last argument. So when you try to call the `promisify`d function and pass in an argument, it will take that argument -- the delay-- and try to call it like a function. Of course that's an error.

For entertainment (and slight educational) purposes only, you can pass in a function that reverses the arguments and it will work:

```
let util = require('util')

let pause = util.promisify((a, f) => setTimeout(f, a))
pause(2000)
.then(() => console.log("done"))
```

Now the final argument of the function you passed to `promisify` expects function. But the `asyn/await` method is **so** much nicer…

Comment: I am entertained - and educated! :p

Comment: You say `But the asyn/await method is so much nicer` - but that still requires a promisified timeout, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you still need to create the promise, but I think  `util.promisify` with the reversed arguments is very confusing. Maybe **so** much nicer was a bit of an overstatement.

Comment: `let p = util.promisify(setTimeout.bind(null, cb=>cb()));` seems to work :p (for more amusement and education)

Comment: how do you think I felt writing it :p

Comment: [setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) The document note: This method has a custom variant for promises that is available using util.promisify()

Answer (score 8):

You know that this right here works:

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const sleep = promisify(setTimeout);

;(async () => {

  const ts = Date.now()

  await sleep(5000)

  console.log(Date.now()-ts)

})();
```

This works fine, why not go with it and use it???

Comment: Concise example.

Answer (score 7):

This can be a one-liner: `await promisify(setTimeout)(1000)`.

It works because setTimeout has a [custom variant for promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63496741/161182). It does work with node 8.11.

```
nvm install 8.11 && nvm use 8.11
node <<HEREDOC
  (async () => {
    // const start = Date.now();
    await require('util').promisify(setTimeout)(5000);
    // console.log(Date.now() - start);
  })()
HEREDOC
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
```

Is the essence of the implementation of `util.promisify(setTimeout)`, but there are additional features to the `promisify` implementation:

- it takes an optional value argument that is returned as the value of the promise

```js
setTimeoutPromisify(10, 'foo bar').then(value => console.log(value)) // logs "foo bar"
console.log(await setTimeoutPromisify(10, 'foo bar')) // logs "foo bar"
```

- it takes an (optional) options argument that

  - lets you specify an [`AbortController`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_class_abortcontroller) `signal` to cancel the timeout
  - lets you choose whether or not to keep a [`ref`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_unref), which if set to false, means the program will exit before the timeout finishes if nothing else is happening

```js
const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = ac.signal;

setTimeoutPromisify(1000, 'foo bar', { signal, ref: true })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.name === 'AbortError')
      console.log('The timeout was aborted');
  })

controller.abort()
```

For more information see https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html

The implementation in node 16 is below:

```js
function setTimeout(after, value, options = {}) {
  const args = value !== undefined ? [value] : value;
  if (options == null || typeof options !== 'object') {
    return PromiseReject(
      new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
        'options',
        'Object',
        options));
  }
  const { signal, ref = true } = options;
  try {
    validateAbortSignal(signal, 'options.signal');
  } catch (err) {
    return PromiseReject(err);
  }
  if (typeof ref !== 'boolean') {
    return PromiseReject(
      new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
        'options.ref',
        'boolean',
        ref));
  }

  if (signal && signal.aborted) {
    return PromiseReject(new AbortError());
  }
  let oncancel;
  const ret = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timeout = new Timeout(resolve, after, args, false, true);
    if (!ref) timeout.unref();
    insert(timeout, timeout._idleTimeout);
    if (signal) {
      oncancel = FunctionPrototypeBind(cancelListenerHandler,
                                       timeout, clearTimeout, reject);
      signal.addEventListener('abort', oncancel);
    }
  });
  return oncancel !== undefined ?
    PromisePrototypeFinally(
      ret,
      () => signal.removeEventListener('abort', oncancel)) : ret;
}
```