# How does `await promisify(setTimeout)(ms)` work when the callback is missing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, settimeout, node-promisify

For a simple async sleep function in JavaScript, `await promisify(setTimeout)(ms)` works!

But how? The arguments look wrong.

- [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) passes an error callback, so the
- [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) call would be `setTimeout(ms, errorCallback)`

which should not work, yet it does. How?

---

```js
import { promisify } from 'util'
(async () => {
  // const start = Date.now()
  await promisify(setTimeout)(1000)
  // console.log(Date.now() - start)
})()
```

```
node <<HEREDOC
  (async () => {
    // const start = Date.now();
    await require('util').promisify(setTimeout)(1000);
    // console.log(Date.now() - start);
  })()
HEREDOC
```

---

Background: `await setTimeout(() => {}, 1000)` [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292942/161182). This [one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51939030/161182): `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))` did not work for me (why?). We can [promisify it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33292942/161182): `const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)); await sleep(1000)`, but that is an [extra function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51796014/161182). We can do better.

Comment: `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));` works fine, you make something up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `setTimeout` has [a custom promisified function](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/util.html#util_custom_promisified_functions) now. You can find it when you print `setTimeout`.

```
> console.log(setTimeout)
{ [Function: setTimeout] [Symbol(util.promisify.custom)]: [Function] }
undefined
```

Common functions that take a callback not in the standard way may have a custom promisified function, and `util.promisify` returns it when a function has a custom promisified function.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` is a **special case** for `promisify`.

Per the [node.js specs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args):

> Note: This method has a custom variant for promises that is available using util.promisify()
>
> ```js
> const util = require('util');
> const setTimeoutPromise = util.promisify(setTimeout);
>
> setTimeoutPromise(40, 'foobar').then((value) => {
>  // value === 'foobar' (passing values is optional)
>  // This is executed after about 40 milliseconds.
> });
> ```

With async/await, that becomes:

```js
await promisify(setTimeout)(1000)
```